# Custom anti-forgery token filter method not getting invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following custom method to validate anti forgery token.

```
public class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public const string UNAUTHORIZED_TEXT = "Unauthorized";

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

            var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null ? antiForgeryCookie.Value : null;

            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the token in the view as follows

```
<div class="NewWt" id="PageType" style="margin-top:10px;display:none;float:left;">
    <span id="i18n-13">@Model.SaveAsNewWtText</span>
    <input id="chkBoxWelcome" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <span>@Model.WelcomeText</span>
    <input id="chkBoxHub" type="checkbox">
    <span>@Model.HubText</span>
    **<span>@Html.AntiForgeryToken()</span>**
</div>
```

I call it here on top of a my `post` method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("api/WT")]
    [AllowAnonymous]

    public WT Post([FromBody]Widget widget, [FromUri]string pageType)
    {  ..... }
```

I put a breakpoint in the `ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken` but the breakpoint is not getting hit. The filter method is not getting invoked. I even registered it in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in the `App_Start` but still not getting invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to derive from AuthorizeAttribute not FilterAttribute.

Comment: @Scott, I already tried that but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've implemented a MVC authorization filter, considering its signature:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd492255%28v%3dvs.100%29

WebAPI authorization filters implement interfaces of the same name but from a different namespace and the filter method signature should be

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/mt175049(v%3dvs.118)

An MVC filter will never work in the WebAPI pipeline and vice versa. Though I admit, the similarity of filter names / interfaces could be confusing.